# Unable to access wifi router admin portal

Tags: networking, dns, router

I have been using the router admin security settings to restrict access to some specific sites. The router admin portal is on the gateway ip address.

This has been working quite well for me till yesterday. For some reason, I am unable to access the admin portal since today morning. It doesn't matter which browser or device I use, I am unable to access the admin portal. I have not changed any settings on the router other than adding keywords to restrict internet access.

On a whim, I tried connecting to the router using a LAN cable and after disabling wifi, I was able to connect to the admin portal.

What could have changed to cause this behaviour? How can I fix this so that I can access the router admin portal from wifi also?

I am on a mac machine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. There is a setting called hide LMUI from wifi network. I found this was switched on. Don't remember doing this but switching it off enabled me to access the admin portal on wifi also.